# Try...Catch in PowerShell Functions

Tags: powershell, try-catch, powershell-3.0

I have a main PowerShell script which calls multiple functions, and I have `try...catch` blocks inside each of the functions. Is this a good practice? Or should I use only one try and catch block for the main script?

Comment: That depends on what your code does, which exceptions you want to handle, and how you want to handle them.

Comment: Really depends what you are looking for. Would not think you would put whole functions in a try catch. Also you might need to address the same error in different ways depending on your need. Keeping the separate might be a good idea. Cannot tell without a specific example

Comment: The multiple functions am talking about are not really complex and i have somewhere around 20 functions to be called from the mail script. i do want to have try..catch for certain complex once. Also am writing the source of the exception (from which function) into the log and wanted to maintain a standard by using it across all functions. Just thinking if this would lead to any performance set backs ?. Is that poor coding by any means ?

Answer (score 0):

IMPO - If modifying infrastructure objects is what you intend to do, then try{}catch{} is the thing that covers your backside.  I find it's the best way to catch both known and unknown errors and translate to 'human' language.  Something which is essential if you are developing solutions for operational staff who don't understand code.